# Javascript variables in Jquery function for better use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on html5 min and max date range function.

I wrote a code in variables and then use in right attribute places.

My client (code reviewer) says that this code is not look nice and better is to use in javascrit helper for later use.

Here is my code:

```
var now_html5 = new Date();
var day_html5 = ("0" + now_html5.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month_html5 = ("0" + (now_html5.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today_html5 = now_html5.getFullYear()+"-"+(month_html5)+"-"+(day_html5);
var birth_date_html5 = (now_html5.getFullYear() - 2)+"-"+(month_html5)+"-"+(day_html5);
if (Modernizr.inputtypes.date && is_touch_device() ) {
    $('.date-container input').prop('type','date');
    $('#date-from').attr('max',today_html5);
    $('#date-to').attr('min',today_html5);
    $('#birth-date').attr('max',birth_date_html5);
}
```

How to put date variables in functions to use later on other funcions, definations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what your client means is that you should create functions that returns exactly what you put in your variables.

For instance:

```
function getTodayHtml5() {
    var now_html5 = new Date();
    var day_html5 = ("0" + now_html5.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month_html5 = ("0" + (now_html5.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

    return now_html5.getFullYear()+"-"+(month_html5)+"-"+(day_html5);
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
$('#date-from').attr('max',getTodayHtml5());
```

The same way should be used for birth_date_html5.

Comment: Yes, something like this, but how to return a multiple versions, like `getTodayHtml5(birth_day)` or `getTodayHtml5(today)` of one function, not two different functions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along those lines ?

Using function you can pass any date to start calculations from.

```
function getSplittedDate(date) {
    var d = {
        day: ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2),
        month: ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    };
    d.today = (date.getFullYear()+"-"+(d.month)+"-"+(d.day)),
    d.birth_day = (date.getFullYear() - 2)+"-"+(d.month)+"-"+(d.day)
    return d;
}
var now_html5 = new Date();
console.log(getSplittedDate(now_html5));
// Object {day: "08", month: "05", today: "2014-05-08", birth_day: "2012-05-08"}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wEn8R/)

Comment: And how to return `getSplittedDate(day)` or `getSplittedDate(birth_day)` ?

Comment: To obtain eg birth_day just use `getSplittedDate(now_html5).birth_day`.

Comment: `var now_html5 = new Date();` how to put on function, not outside function? It would be nice, to put all variables intro function. It is possible?